# Migrating a document store from SVN to Sharepoint10

Tags: svn, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I work for a large organisation that has had a somewhat fragmented approach to document / knowledge management. This is now changing and we have been mandated to move to Office 365 and the use of SharePoint 10.

For the last year my project has been using subversion as a document store and I need to find a way to migrate the documents, and document version history and check in comments to SharePoint. The entire repository currently sits at around 300GB, and after trimming the obvious cruft I am still left with ~100GB to migrate. No doubt this can be reduce further, but it gives an idea of the size of the migration.

I've tried googling for this and found a number of other people asking similar questions but with no resolution.

Has anyone any experience with this sort of migration that could point me in the right direction?

Ideally, due to the byzantine purchasing policy implemented by my organisation I'd like to avoid any commercial solutions if possible!

Comment: SVN and SharePoint are different products. AFAIK there is no automated tool to migrate repo data with history to SharePoint. Could you please clarify in your Q what kind of migration do you expect?

BTW why migrate from SVN to SharePoint!?

Comment: Not a solution but an observation - I came across your post when looking for a tool to do the opposite migration :-) We've been struggling with various versions of SharePoint and Office 365 for years and have finally decided to switch to SVN for document control.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to "import" or create document histories on the fly. It would be a tedious affair, as you would need to "reverse" your current versions so the oldest version is current document, import that, then take the next version and import that, and so on.  This would cause SharePoint to create the version histories of the documents.

Another approach to this is to slowly transition by project or team if possible.  Take documents that will have a set Baseline - import those and just start keeping version history from that point forward.  It means you will have two repositories for a time, but you won't lost data you may need.